# Travel with two passports different from previous

Tags: passports, europe, international-travel, dual-nationality

OK I want to travel parts of Europe but my Indian passport won't let me without all via restrictions. I hold a Portuguese national ID issued to me by a consulate as my father is Portuguese. Now India only allows single citizenship but Portugal allows dual.

If I have to leave India with my Portuguese passport I will have to surrender my Indian passport (I love my country so I don't want to leave Indian citizenship, but I love to travel)

Can I take a visa from India to a country where only Portuguese national ID card is required for travel and from there travel to European countries, before going back to the country with the visa to come back to India?

Would that be a problem?

Comment: Will Indian officers check for a Schengen visa when you leave India for a Schengen country?  Most countries' immigration authorities, when performing exit checks, are unconcerned with entry requirements at a traveler's destination.

Comment: Yes. And the Portuguese consulate has been given instructions from the government to not issue visas to Portugal. But I'm getting evesa for Georgia where travel for Portuguese citizen is visa free with national ID card ( which I have)

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't matter whether you can travel in Georgia with your Portuguese ID card because you will travel there with your Indian passport and e Visa.

Comment: @user59683 Don't get an e-visa, no reason. Just a waste of money - you can enter on your Portuguese ID without a visa

Comment: @Crazydre he'll need the e-visa to exit India.  ("Will Indian officers check for a Schengen visa when you leave India for a Schengen country?"; "Yes."  The same is presumably true for trips to other jurisdictions.)  Therefore, if he doesn't have the e-visa, he'll lose his Indian passport.

Comment: @phoog Riiight, bloody Indian nationality law. Completely forgot

Comment: Not a dupe since OP is in the precarious situation of illegally possessing two nationalities. Thus voting to reopen